# simple node client server communication not working using express and socket.io

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to write a simple client server application.

That's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="client.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

*server.js file:*

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const server = app.listen(port);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
});
```

*client.js file:*

```
const socket = io('https://localhost:3000/');
```

At this moment if I start the server by typing *node server* on the terminal and I open the HTML file using the LiveServer vs extension, the console doesn't show the text *a user connected*, it also returns an error which is:

> GET
> https://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NdZ4wOd
> net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: you probably don't have an SSL certificate running and should be using http:// instead

Comment: @Kwright02 I've already tried it, it shows more errors: 

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NdZ9GyU' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NdZ9GyU:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: This means you haven't enabled cors in express, but it also leads me to wonder what you're actually trying to do here.

Comment: @Kwright02 I'm following this tutorial, it seems to work for him: https://youtu.be/PXBy6pB4mTU

Comment: @Seo I'm not sure how liveserver exactly works but it looks like its serving the index.html file from port 5500 while your backend is running on 3000 hence the cors error. Fortunately socketio has a nice documentation to solve it: https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/. You can also serve the index.html directly from your express server, in that case you wouldn't need to configure cors.

Answer (score 0):

In the client.js file you could try `const socket = io.connect();` and I'm not sure but i think `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js"></script>` Should be in the header but i could be wrong about that.

Answer (score 0):

**Make Changes In Your Server File **

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.use(cors());
const server = app.listen(port);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
});
```

**Install cors npm package before starting your server using `npm i cors`**

Comment: It says "Identifier 'express' has already been declared", I think I just need to remove the "const" from the second line.

Comment: No it was my mistake of copy paste, i have edited my code in answer please try now.

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work, I don't know if what I do is right, I opened the html file with liveserver and I changed the port in the server and client files to 5501, (which is the one where the file opens using liveserver)